# Making bat file in Window Mobile 6

Tags: command-line, batch-file, windows-mobile

I have Windows mobile 6. I have installed Cre-ME+, and command line. In the command line we need to type the following command and execute it, to load Oracle Mobile Application:

```
\Windows\CrEme\bin\CrEme.exe -Of -classpath \Windows\CrEme\lib\AWTclasses.zip;\XONTMWA\lib\j4205328.zip oracle.apps.mwa.awt.client.StartGUI
```

However, Windows Mobile does not support the bat/cmd file execution, so what would be a equivalent way of starting the Oracle Mobile Application, without having to type the command every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shortcut with the command line, either [via API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453680.aspx) or [with your favorite text editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861519.aspx).

The contents would look like this (if my character count is right anyway):

`139#\Windows\CrEme\bin\CrEme.exe -Of -classpath \Windows\CrEme\lib\AWTclasses.zip;\XONTMWA\lib\j4205328.zip oracle.apps.mwa.awt.client.StartGUI`